# Next js SSR not working if the website gone to 404 page

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

I implement ssr for my page and it is working on the first load but then when i go to some unknown pages (the website throw the 404 page) and try to go back to the ssr page using the navigation, it show undefined properties, is there something wrong with the navigation?

The navigation page :

```js
import Link from "next/link";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";

export function Navigation() {
  const router = useRouter();

  return (
    <div className="fixed top-0 w-full">
      <div className="flex justify-center p-4 space-x-4 text-sm text-gray-500">
        <Link href="/">Home</Link>
        <Link href="/me-ssr">SSR</Link>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

The SSR page:

```js
import { useUser } from "../context/user.context";
import {FC} from 'react'
import { GetServerSidePropsContext } from "next";
import { fetcherSSR } from "../lib/fether-ssr";

const MeSSR: FC = () => {
  const {user} = useUser()

  return (
    <main className="flex items-center justify-center h-full">
      <div className="text-center space-y-4">
        <h1 className="px-4 py-2 text-lg font-medium bg-gray-200 rounded">
          Server side authentication
        </h1>
        <p>Hi, {user!.id} </p>
      </div>
    </main>
  )
}

export default MeSSR



export const getServerSideProps = async (ctx: GetServerSidePropsContext) => {
    const {req, res} = ctx;
    const [error, user] = await fetcherSSR(req, res, 'http://localhost:3000/user/profile')

    if(!user) return {redirect: {statusCode:307, destination: '/login'}}
    return {props:{user}}
}
```

Comment: probably because you're using `FC` instead of `NextPage` as a type from `import { NextPage } from 'next'`;

Comment: Hey thanks for the comment, I have tried to set it to NextPage, unfortunately, it still the same

Comment: `getServerSideProps` will pass the user to the page via props, why not just get the user from page props? `const MeSSR: NextPage<{user: User}> = ({user}) =>{}`